# C# - Button Enabled Disabled According Listbox

Tags: c#, button, listbox, selectedindexchanged

The scenario like that; firstly my button disabled. As long as the selected index in the table is equal to -1 and the number of elements in the table is 0, the button will be disabled. I coded it like this but it doesn't work;

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1 && listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Note: The code does not fail but does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: try to change your `if` like => `if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1 && listBox1.Items.Count == 0)`

Comment: Do I need another function or something else in your opinion? @er-sho

Comment: by changing if condition to above what happens?

Comment: Please describe "does not work". What exactly are you expecting that did not happen?

Comment: When I click to run, my button wasn't disabled, I could click on it. And I could click when my listbox empty.

Comment: Is your button disabled on app start?

Comment: Yes, of course it is, because the SelectedIndex will not change on Startup and therefor that method will not run. Use a breakpoint and the debugger to check that ;o)

Comment: @er-sho i tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: @SirRufo how should I do it?

Comment: It never change. It always enabled.

Comment: Call that code not only on SelectedIndexChange but also on Startup

Comment: @SirRufo okay i did it. I changed location of button1.Enabled = false to in Form1, and i deleted listbox.Items.Count condition, listbox.selectedindex != -1 is enough for it, because we are filling 'selectedindex' funciton, it doesn't accept listbox.items, it works for selectedindex.

Comment: @ImaNewCoder If you have an answer your own question, then you should add an answer to this question and accept it. Do not update the question with the answer details. Remember you are on a Question&Answer site and its dna is having questions with (hopefully accepted) answers ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo i edited my answer, have a good day.

Comment: Please do not forget to accept your answer as well, so this question will appear to others as answered ;o) (Maybe you have to wait some time to accept it)

Comment: @SirRufo I have to wait 2 days, after that I will accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I changed location of `button1.Enabled = false` to in Form3, and I deleted `listbox.Items.Count` condition. `listbox.selectedindex != -1` is enough for this job, because we are filling 'selectedindex' function, it doesn't accept `listbox.items`, it works for selected index.

```
 public Form3()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     button1.Enabled = false;
 }

 private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
     {
         button1.Enabled = true;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Hide();
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex!=-1&&listBox1.SelectedIndex>0)
        {
            button1.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Hide();
        }
    }
```

> **Try this**

Comment: I did it with another solution. I changed location of button1.Enabled = false to in Form1, and i deleted listbox.Items.Count condition. listbox.selectedindex != -1 is enough for this job, because we are filling 'selectedindex' funciton, it doesn't accept listbox.items, it works for selectedindex. Thanks anyway.